# Add item json in ANGULAR with pop-up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, modal-dialog, ngtable

I'm doing a web app.

I have a dynamic **table**. First, you choose a **PRODUCT** and then the **LOT**. The list of item in the select are taken by json. Now the problem is that I want to add the possibility to create new item to add in the `<select>` **LOT**.

So, first I tried to add the field in the **LOT** column using the following codes:

```
  $scope.addLot = function(id,val,lotId) { 
    // console.log(id);
    var inWhichProduct = id;
    var newArray = { "value": val, "id": lotId };
   //console.log($scope.items)
    angular.forEach($scope.items,function(v,i){
      if($scope.items[i].id == id )
      {
        $scope.items[i].lots.push(newArray);
        console.log($scope.items[i].lots);
      }
    });
  };
```

and it works ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W8eche8eIEUuDBsRpLse?p=preview) is an example). But what I want to do is move those fields in a modal window. I tried this, but it doesn't work ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/d592JsS6VznPmzcEyDJm?p=preview) is another example). Why? Maybe the correct way is to add the item in the json and then refresh the **LOT**, but how can I add the item in the json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.infos = [
            {name: "i will go to modal 1"},
            {name: "i will go to modal 2"}
          ];

          $scope.goToModal = function(info) {
            $scope.newDataInModal = info;
          }
        }
      ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <!-- start container -->
  
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr ng-repeat="info in infos">
        <td>
          {{info.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="goToModal(info)">
            Launch demo modal
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>



  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{newDataInModal.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- close container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't understand how I could integrate your code with mine